# Navigate to deeply nested screen with React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Image the following navigation structure:

```
RootNavigator
   AppNavigator
      TabNavigator
         Home
         Profile
```

How do I navigate to the `Home`Screen from the top? I tried something like `navigation.navigate("AppNavigator", { screen: 'TabNavigator', { screen: 'Home' }})` and `navigation.navigate("AppNavigator", { component: 'TabNavigator', { screen: 'Home' }})` but neither seemed to work. The docs don't really tell how to navigate to screen deeper nested than one level - does anybody have an idea how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: try some-thing like this. 
     navigation.navigate('Root', {
        screen: 'Settings',
        params: {
          screen: 'Sound',
              params: {
               screen: 'Media',
           },
   },
});

i hope this will help .

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're in `RootNavigator` or a sibling of `AppNavigator`

```js
navigation.navigate("AppNavigator", {
  screen: "TabNavigator",
  params: {
    screen: "Home",
  },
});
```

works for `@react-navigation/native@^6`